# What can be said about the number of connected components of $G(n,p)$ random graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

By a $G(n,p)$ graph we mean a graph on $n$ vertices, all possible edges are independently included randomly with probability $p$.

What can be said about the number of connected components? For example, bounds or asymptotic behavior of the expected number of components as $n\rightarrow \infty$ or for $p$ close to 1.

Comment: $p$ is constant? The wiki page has something: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model#Properties_of_G.28n.2C_p.29, which _seems_ to imply that the expected number for constant $p$ will be $\Omega(n/\log n)$.

Comment: I take it you've seen the results for large $p$ here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erdos-Renyi_model ?

Comment: For constant $p$, the wikipedia page implies that your graph is almost surely connected as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @Aryabhata You're probably thinking of $np$ being constant.

Comment: @ErickWong: No, I was thinking of the case $np \to \infty$, where there is one giant component, and the remaining components are of size $O(\log n)$.

Comment: @Aryabhata The wiki page explicitly calls this the $np=c$ case, not $np\to\infty$.  As EuYu points out when $p$ is constant (or just a bit higher than $\Omega(1/n)$), the graph has only one component.

Comment: @ErickWong: Yes, I misread, thanks!

Comment: @muzzlator The link you gave shows the behavior for $n\rightarrow \infty$. But you mentioned "results for large p". Excuse me but I am confused.

Comment: You said you wanted to know about the number of connected components. When $p$ is less than a certain amount, the results on that page only say the graph isn't connected.  On the other hand when $p$ exceeds a certain amount, it says that as $n \rightarrow \infty$, the graph is almost surely connected so that the number of connected components approaches $1$.

Comment: @muzzlator The statement that $\mathbb{P}(G_{n,p} \text{ is not connected}) = o(1)$ does not, of course, imply that the expected number of components is bounded.  Or is it easy to see that the variance of the number of components is not too large?

Comment: @AndrewUzzell Hi, looks like I misread the wiki article because I didn't notice the $p$ there was dependent on $n$.  For a fixed $p$, what EuYu said applies, the graph will almost surely be connected as $n$ approaches infinity.